# Looping through agridt in JSP

Tags: jsp, datagrid

please help me I'm a beginner. Please let me know how can I iterate/loop through a dataGrid in JSP(JavaServer Pages). I need to show employee details in the below dataGrid. But I don't know how to display the details in the grid. Also please help me regarding, what is the **name ="" & dataSource=""** in the dataGrid. Thank you in advance.

```
<netui-data:dataGrid name="" dataSource="">
    <netui-data:configurePager disableDefaultPager="true" />
    <netui-data:header>
        <netui-data:headerCell headerText="Id" />
        <netui-data:headerCell headerText="First Name" />
        <netui-data:headerCell headerText="Last Name" />
        <netui-data:headerCell headerText="Email" />
    </netui-data:header>
    <netui-data:rows>
        <netui-data:spanCell value=""></netui-data:spanCell>
        <netui-data:spanCell value=""></netui-data:spanCell>
        <netui-data:spanCell value=""></netui-data:spanCell>
        <netui-data:spanCell value=""></netui-data:spanCell>
    </netui-data:rows>
</netui-data:dataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the NetUI tag library appears to no longer be supported. The [Apache Beehive](http://beehive.apache.org) project for it has been put into the attic, and the documentation is no longer available, as far as I can tell.

However, there is [a usage example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13224_01/wlw/docs103/guide/webapplications/netui/tutorial/tutWebAppStep3.html.) that might be helpful. See the very bottom of that page for the example.

In that example, it appears that the value of `name` is not significant, but the value of `dataSource` apparently only needs to be something that produces a list of objects. Further, each object from that data source appears to then be referenced as a bean named `container` within the expressions of the `value` attributes of the `spanCell` tags.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, I helped me but the usage example is not working.

Comment: Instead of dataGrid I used tables to show the data. that solved my problem, but still I don't know how to use grids

Comment: If you paste your working code, then perhaps I can help you to get things to work with the `netui-data` tags. However, given that the tag library seems to be "dead," it may not be worth your time to use it. You may want to find an alternative tag library to fit your needs. The `jstl` might be sufficient. In any case, if you care to share your working code, I'd be glad to try to help further.

Comment: thank you my friend my problem is solved. If I use the netui-data I will sure come back to you.